# If a unique value is anywhere in one column and another column, return paid, else unpaid

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I've been trying to use formulas to get a Google Spreadsheet working the way I need it to. I'm almost there, but I can't seem to target all rows in `C` and `E` with the `find` function. Since Google Forms adds a new row when it's resubmitted, I need to find a workaround that looks for a value in the spreadsheet and marks it as true or false (in my case paid or unpaid) when someone submits a form and fills out a new value in it. The value would match another value somewhere in the spreadsheet.

Hopefully this makes sense. I looked all over Stack Overflow but couldn't quite find the answer to my question.

Screenshot of the spreadsheet: http://cl.ly/image/232t063u2x1g

Comment: @pnuts They're blank because we wanted to automate the system a little bit and add the paid license plate using the same form that we added the original one, but only filling out that field.

Comment: I want to show the results in another column. Yes, there will only be a single instance.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, *anywhere*.

Answer (score 0):

Then you could try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(E1:E="","Unpaid","Paid"))
```

Comment: Not quite. I'm looking for it to match the exact value as found anywhere else in the spreadsheet. I'm not sure if it's even possible without custom scripting.